# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

File "/home/abir/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/models/ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 33, in 
from official.vision.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official'

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the module `tf-models-official`.

- First open Command Prompt in Windows or Terminal in Linux/Mac.
- In windows make sure `pip` is in path, then run:

```
pip install -U tf-models-official
```

- If you have multiple versions then its better to:
  `pipVERSION install -U tf-models-official` Where VERSION is like `pip3.7`

Comment: ValueError: ssd_mobilenet_v1 is not supported. See `model_builder.py` for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JR8CmWyh2E8&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcNK5GeCQnxYnSSaar2tpku&index=5&ab_channel=sentdex  i am following this

Comment: ValueError: ssd_mobilenet_v1 is not supported. See model_builder.py for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on terminal:

```
pip install tf-models-official
```

Comment: ValueError: ssd_mobilenet_v1 is not supported. See model_builder.py for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow           https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JR8CmWyh2E8&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcNK5GeCQnxYnSSaar2tpku&index=5&ab_channel=sentdex    ( i was trying this)

Answer (score 0):

The following packages need to be installed in cmd:

```
pip install -U tf-models-official
```

Comment: add "-f" at the end of the command :" pip install -U tf-models-official -f "   This will forcingly make the packages get installed in case if anything is deprecated.

Comment: ValueError: ssd_mobilenet_v1 is not supported. See model_builder.py for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow